# Cannot find element for dotnet test id: error in Resharper 2016.3

Tags: unit-testing, resharper-2016

I just downloaded Resharper 2016.3 EAP 4 to check out the Unit test functionality with .NET Core. But when I run all unit tests, I get this error:

> Cannot find element for dotnet test id:
>   MvcMovieTests.SimpleTests.TestMethodPassing
>
> Cannot find element for dotnet test id:
>   MvcMovieTests.SimpleTests.TestMethodFailing

Here are my simple unit tests:

```
[TestClass]
public class SimpleTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethodPassing()
    {
        Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.Assert.IsTrue(true);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethodFailing()
    {
        Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.Assert.IsTrue(false);
    }
}
```

When I run all unit tests with the MSTEST Test Explorer, they run properly and I see the results. But with Resharper 2016.3 I get the two errors above showing up in the Unit Test Sessions window in Visual Studio 2015 Community.

Comment: Clearing up the ReSharper caches fixed it up for me. Open the Environment | General page of ReSharper options. Click Clear caches. More information here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2016.3/Configuring_Caches_Location.html

Comment: @Gabriel Clearing R# caches also fixed the problem for me. You should make that comment an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearing up the `ReSharper` caches fixed it up for me. Open the `Environment | General` page of `ReSharper` options. Click `Clear caches`. More information [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Configuring_Caches_Location.html#cleanup).